# Scrape website (Excel vba) with xml http request after cookie has been set

Tags: excel, vba, cookies, xmlhttprequest, screen-scraping

I would like to scrape a website (extract a product price) from a single website page (with XML HTTP request). But before this script should run I need to have selected the correct store first (saved in browser cookie variable or included in any other way/request if possible) since prices are different in different shops.

I have created a working code but it's taking a very long time to run so i assume there must be faster and cleaner :) way. I also needed to include the application to wait for the website to follow the steps.

My current vba code:

- runs a HTTP IE request to open the website, and in multiple clicks selects the desired store and saves it in a cookie (like a site user should do)
- next the product page is requested with another HTTP IE request and data is extracted. I found out a can't use the XML HTTP request because it won't use the cookie value with the correct store, displaying the correct price.
- The price i'm after (in the example below) is E 1,39 instead of E 1,48 (when no cookie value is used and no store is selected).
- The cookie value is saved in the cookie "www.jumbo.com/cookie/HomeStore the Content is holding the store tag which is known upfront and could be hardcoded in a request if possible.

**Selecting the correct store (and saving it in a browser cookie)**

```
   Sub SetStore()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Dim HTMLSearchbox As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLSearchboxes As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLSearchButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLSearchButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLStoreID As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLStoreIDs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLSaveStore As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLSaveStores As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection


   'set on False to hide IE screen
    IE.Visible = True

    'navigate to url with limited content
    IE.navigate "https://www.jumbo.com/content/algemene-voorwaarden/"

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Loop
    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

    Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")


    For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons

        If HTMLButton.getAttribute("data-jum-action") = "openHomeStoreFinder" Then
           HTMLButton.Click
            Exit For
        End If

     Next HTMLButton


       Application.Wait Now + #12:00:02 AM#

    Set HTMLSearchboxes = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

    For Each HTMLSearchbox In HTMLSearchboxes

     If HTMLSearchbox.getAttribute("id") = "searchTerm__DkKYx4XylsAAAFJktpb2Guy" Then


    'input field store name/location to show search results
    HTMLSearchbox.Value = "Oosterhout"

           Application.Wait Now + #12:00:03 AM#

           HTMLSearchbox.Click

            Exit For
        End If

     Next HTMLSearchbox

     Set HTMLSearchButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

    For Each HTMLSearchButton In HTMLSearchButtons

        If HTMLSearchButton.getAttribute("data-jum-filter") = "search" Then
            HTMLSearchButton.Click

            Exit For
        End If

    Next HTMLSearchButton

    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:05 AM#

    Set HTMLStoreIDs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("li")

    For Each HTMLStoreID In HTMLStoreIDs


  'oosterhout = YC8KYx4XB88AAAFIDcIYwKxJ
  'nieuwegein = 84IKYx4XziUAAAFInSYYwKrH
  'vaassen = JYYKYx4XC1oAAAFItvcYwKxJ
  'brielle = OG8KYx4XP4wAAAFIlsEYwKxK

     If HTMLStoreID.getAttribute("data-jum-store-id") = "YC8KYx4XB88AAAFIDcIYwKxJ" Then


     HTMLStoreID.Click

      Application.Wait Now + #12:00:03 AM#

          Exit For
      End If


  Next HTMLStoreID

  Set HTMLSaveStores = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")


  For Each HTMLSaveStore In HTMLSaveStores

        If HTMLSaveStore.getAttribute("data-jum-action") = "saveHomeStore" Then
            HTMLSaveStore.Click


            Exit For
       End If

    Next HTMLSaveStore


   'IE.Quit

End Sub
```

**Extracting data from product page (IE HTTP request, working with cookie store value)**

```
Sub GetJumboPriceIE()


Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim JumInputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim JumInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim JumPrice As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim JumboPrice As Double
Dim Price_In_Cents_Tag As String

Dim SKU_tag As String, SKU_url As String

SKU_tag = "173140KST"
SKU_url = "https://www.jumbo.com/lu-bastogne-koeken-original-260g/173140KST/"

IE.Visible = False
   IE.navigate SKU_url



    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop


    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

    IE.Quit


Set JumInputs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

Price_In_Cents_Tag = "PriceInCents_" & SKU_tag

Set JumPrice = HTMLDoc.getElementById(Price_In_Cents_Tag)


JumboPrice = JumPrice.getAttribute("value") / 100
Debug.Print JumboPrice


End Sub
```

The code above is working but would like to use XML HTTP request code like below (but using the correct store). The price of 1,39 is printed.

**Extracting data from product page (using XML HTTP request), but cookie value is not used**

```
Sub GetJumboPriceXML()

Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim JumInputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim JumInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim JumPrice As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim JumboPrice As Double
Dim Price_In_Cents_Tag As String

Dim SKU_tag As String, SKU_url As String

SKU_tag = "173140KST"
SKU_url = "https://www.jumbo.com/lu-bastogne-koeken-original-260g/173140KST/"


XMLReq.Open "GET", SKU_url, False
XMLReq.send

If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then

MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
 Exit Sub
 End If

  HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

Set JumInputs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")


Price_In_Cents_Tag = "PriceInCents_" & SKU_tag

Set JumPrice = HTMLDoc.getElementById(Price_In_Cents_Tag)

JumboPrice = JumPrice.getAttribute("value") / 100
Debug.Print JumboPrice



End Sub
```

This code is not using the correct store and outputting the price i'm not after (The price 1,48 is printed).

---

To summarize:

When no store is selected (no cookie set) the following URL now gives the price of €1,48.

I would like the VB script to set the store to “Jumbo Oosterhout Nieuwe Bouwlingstraat” and then scrape a predefined list op product URL’s and extract the prices (URL above gives €1,39).

Then set the store to a different local store “Jumbo Brielle Thoelaverweg”  and scrape the identical list of product URL’s. The above URL gives €1,48.

You can select a different store by clicking on the location pin icon at the top right of the page.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hi Maurice. You have to put @qharr for me to be notified of a message in chat. I have only just seen your message. Last I remember I had reached the point that unless  the API designers have a way then I would probably go the long winded way of automating setting the local store between each set of price extractions.

Comment: I raised an issue [here](https://github.com/agentcooper/albert-heijn/issues/3) but no answer as yet.

Comment: @QHarr, sorry i didn't know that :) The question with Albert Heijn was solved by your other reply in a different post and works perfect now using the API rest request,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181293/scrape-website-with-xml-http-request-with-excel-vba-wait-for-the-page-to-fully

The current open question is for Jumbo, a different supermarket where the prices are different in different stores. Please let me know if the question is still clear to you. Or i should elaborate/explain more. Thanks!

Comment: Oopsy there! I am losing track

Comment: Hi @Qharr, is there any way you could help me further in this project? Sorry to bother you again! I summarized the question again in the edited topic (at the bottom of the post) with actual prices to illustrate the question. Please let me know if I can help with additional info. Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking. The question is a little hard to follow in its current format but will let you know.

Comment: Are you saying you know how to do this using IE but want to do it with XMLHTTP?

Comment: OK great, please let me know if and how I could explain it more to get a better understanding. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, Using IE it works (opening the browser, setting the cookie and start requesting the pages) but it's really slow. I know the XMLHTTP works faster if only requesting a product page and scrape the price. However I cannot set the cookie and have the XMLHTTP remember the correct local store.

Comment: Are you doing this for lots of stores? How long is long time with IE?

Comment: I would need to extract the prices for 4 different stores. (200 products in the final list). With current IE method it takes up to 15 minutes to extract all 200 products. So it would take at least one hour. There is no need to stick to the XMLHTTP method if there are other faster methods that can be used to get the same output

Comment: Hi @QHarr , do you have any new insights how to tackle this? Sorry for asking again! Thanks Maurice

Comment: I'm so confused as to which ones I have answered! Lol. So, I think I said the easiest would be to automate setting the local store in each case and grabbing the prices. Cookie based XMLHTTP may be time sensitive - not sure what their expiry would be for each store instance.

Comment: Thanks @Qharr, so you suggest to stick with the code I currently have? I think the cookie expiration is set to unlimited. Is there an easier way to set the store in a cookie and refer to that cookie (or Sesssion) in a following product page request (and extract the price)? I think my current way of setting the cookie in IE is not the best code possible :) I could set the different stores (once) in different sessions and refer them to scrape the product pages (and switch sessions in between?) Not sure if that works?