# Cloudflare error with CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xmlhttprequest

I have using this code for ages. It just ask the URL for an ID which is returned in plain text, now, they started using cloudflare in the domain and im getting an error "please enable cookies" with this code:

```
Set objWeb = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objWeb.Open "GET", URL, False
objWeb.send
strXML = objWeb.responsetext
```

Anyone can help me to solve this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208040/scrape-website-excel-vba-with-xml-http-request-after-cookie-has-been-set

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748144/how-to-suppress-cookie-request

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64292885/how-to-get-cookie-information-using-excel-vba